# Apache Pig: Sort a chararray/string column alphabetically

Tags: apache-pig, alphabetical-sort

If I have a table as below:

id:int
name:chararray

How can I order the column 'name' alphabetically in Pig?

Does 'ORDER table by name ASC' do the required? Or does it sort according to the string lengths?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By default ORDER BY will gives you an output in ASC based on the string length. you can check from this example

```
input.txt  
1 ZZ  
2 III
3 II
4 JJJJ
5 Z
6 IIIIII
7 FFF
8 IIII
9 JJ
10 AAA

PigScript:
A = LOAD 'input.txt' using PigStorage(' ') AS (id:int,name:chararray);
B = ORDER A BY name;
DUMP B;

Output:
(10,AAA)
(7,FFF)
(3,II)
(2,III)
(8,IIII)
(6,IIIIII)
(9,JJ)
(4,JJJJ)
(5,Z)
(1,ZZ)
```